# How can I assign the content of a function variable to an option?

Tags: vimscript, variables

This is what U wanted to do:

```
function! Spell(lang)
  if a:lang == "off"
    set nospell
  else
    set spell
    set spelllang=a:lang
  endif
endfunction
```

unfortunately it does not work ;( it assigns the string `a:lang` to `spelllang`.

Comment: See `:h :let-option`

Answer (score 5):

`:exe` and `:let` (and some other commands like `:echo` or `:call`) are basically the only ex commands that expect variables. Almost all other ex commands do not expect such things and therefore take it literally. Therefore you have to use `:exe "set spelllang=".a:lang` or even better, use `:let &spelllang=a:lang` (see `:h :let-option`).